# Time with a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

```
function _editableTime(elementId , index, elementName, val, mandatoryObj){
var timeElement = document.createElement("input");
timeElement.id = elementId;
$(timeElement).attr("placeholder" , "24hr Format Only");
checkReadOnly(timeElement);
var classNames = "form-control input-xs";

if(mandatoryObj && mandatoryObj[elementName]){
    classNames += " mandate";
    var mandateObj = mandatoryObj[elementName];

    if(mandateObj && mandateObj['alertMsg']){
        $(timeElement).attr("alert-message" , mandateObj['alertMsg']);
    }
}

$(timeElement).attr("class", classNames);

if(val){
    timeElement.value = val;

}

if(timeElement.addEventListener){
timeElement.addEventListener("focus",function() {return $(timeElement).timepicker({
     'step': 15,'timeFormat' : 'H:i','minTime': '06:00am'}).on('changeTime', function() {
            $(timeElement).timepicker('hide')});});
}else{
    timeElement.attachEvent("focus",function() {return $(timeElement).timepicker({
        'step': 15,'timeFormat' : 'H:i','minTime': '06:00am'}).on('changeTime', function() {
            $(timeElement).timepicker('hide')});});
}
return timeElement;
```

}

**How to make the time range as Early Morning - 5am - 7am
Morning - 7am - 12
afternoon - 12 - 4pm
Evening - 4pm to 7pm
Night - 7pm to 11pm
Late Night - 11pm - 5am
**

Comment: Can you please add your html code too?

Comment: I'm rendering data using a generic function